# Avoiding "Open and repair" message with errors

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a lot of files opening (in loop) by macros.
Some of this file might be corrupted.
To open file I'm using "Open and repair" command (I don't know which file is corrupted).

And I don't know how to avoid displaying a window with error message in a document.
I don't care about this errors (other macros fix it), always I have to click "OK" button.

Is there way to automatically click "OK" or "Open and repair" wihout message?
I always open file in that way:

```
Dim doc as Document
Set doc = Documents.Open(fileName:=fullFileName, OpenAndRepair:=True, AddTORecentFiles:=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution

Using:

```
Documents.OpenNoRepairDialog method
```

instead

```
Documents.Open
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.documents.opennorepairdialog